# Prevent app.config from being created in a Class Library

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

**Background:**
I've created a Visual Studio 2010 solution with a separate project for a Web Application project and Class Library for the business logic. I want the connections and other application settings defined within Web Application project and not have a config file for the Class Library. Something within the Class Library continues to recreate the app.config file even after I've deleted the file. My guess it is related to the LINQ to SQL dbml files.

**Question**
Does anyone know of a way to prevent the app.config from being auto generated in a Class Library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't prevent app.config being generated.

I see no problem with Class library having it's own config file. I do MVC Web projects (same as winforms, webforms or any other project type) with numerous Class libraries each having it's own app.config.

Connection strings are stored only in main MVC project. Upon deployment either don't deploy those config files or delete connection strings from them. As long as they (connection strings) have the same name, class library will find it in main project's config and use it from there.